# Slide div from x,y to x,y?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When someone click on my fields on my virtual game, i get my current left and top cordinates with this:

```
 function moveDiv(fromSeat, toSeat){
    var fromTop  = $('#seat-' + fromSeat).css("top");
    var fromLeft = $('#seat-' + fromSeat).css("left");

    var toTop  = $('#seat-' + toSeat).css("top");
    var toLeft = $('#seat-' + toSeat).css("left");

    /** Move a div from point {"fromTop", "fromLeft"} => {"toTop", "topLeft"} **/
  }
```

I am stuck here, i tried to make a $('...').animate({}); but could not get it working.
I want div "#test" to move from point {"fromTop", "fromLeft"} => {"toTop", "topLeft"}

Comment: You would not need the origin unless there is no origin and you wanted to move to two separate points. Otherwise, `$('#seat-' + fromSeat).animate({ top: toTop, left: toLeft}, duration);` will handle all the calculations for you.

Comment: probably need to add tops together and add lefts and use totals for animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to add the top values and add the left values and do animation using the totals

```
function moveDiv(fromSeat, toSeat){
    var fromTop  = $('#seat-' + fromSeat).css("top");
    var fromLeft = $('#seat-' + fromSeat).css("left");

    var toTop  = $('#seat-' + toSeat).css("top");
    var toLeft = $('#seat-' + toSeat).css("left");

     var position={ top: fromTop+ toTop, left: fromLeft+toLeft}

     $('#seat-' + fromSeat).animate( position);

  }
```

**EDIT:** need to convert values from string containing `px` to number to add them. Can use `parseInt()` to do it